# bootstrap keep 4 pic in line even if style hide

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i have code have 4 pic in line via bootstrap
but ihave function that hide some pic , and that cuz line get less than 4 pic
is there an way to make them alwas be 4 in line even if i hide some,
like replace , and if i show them they camback as the first .

simple code here :
https://jsfiddle.net/7o8tfgup/1/

i have two func hide and show

```
function remo(){

document.getElementById("v2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("v4").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("v7").style.display = "none";
}
function remo2(){

document.getElementById("v2").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("v4").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("v7").style.display = "block";
}
```

so if i click hide
i wanna see :

V1  V3  V5  V6

V8

and not

V1  V3

V5  V6  V8

i try to make js code to make them in place but i faild .and also i removed the div row but not work .

thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7o8tfgup/2/) to make it running. You have to adjust the following points:

1) `col-ms-3` is not a valid bootstrap class. I think you want to use `<div class="col-sm-3">` (small devices and up) or `<div class="col-3">` (all devices). Have a look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

2) If you want to solve your problem you can not use `<div class="row">` for each row. BUT you can create one parent row and put all items in there. Using `<div class="col-sm-3">` or `<div class="col-3">` ensures you will get 4 items a `row`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
    <div class="col-3">
    <div class="col-3">
    <div class="col-3">
    <!-- row two will automatically start -->
    <div class="col-3">
    <div class="col-3">
    <div class="col-3">
    <div class="col-3">
</div>
```

3) You use `document.getElementById("v2").style.display` to hide and show elements but your structure is the following:

```
<div class="col-3"> 
    <div id="v1">
```

What you actually want is hide / show the parent of the element's id, so use `document.getElementById("v2").parentNode.style.display` instead.

**Hint:** Pictures with different sizes can produce errors while displaying. You need to further investigate and add `class="row"` dynamically.

Comment: thank youuu , i learn a lot from this , i will learn more about grid ,thank you for your time u save me :) .